# Does LINQ update whole object in db if only one column is changed?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

If an object has more than one column and program updates only one column, does LINQ update all columns in database no matter if they are changed or not or it updates only changed column(s)?

Example class:

```
MyObject
{
    int ID {get; set}
    string Field1 {get; set}
    string Field2 {get; set}
    string Field3 {get; set}
    string Field4 {get; set}
    string Field5 {get; set}
}
```

Now, I grab a recod from db and change only one field

```
var myObject= 
(
   from x in db.TableName
   where x.ID == 12345
   select x
)
.Single();

myObject.Field1 = "something";

db.SubmitChanges();
```

Does SQL query perform an update statement on all columns or only Field1 column?

Comment: I imagine the compiled update statement is for all columns.  (You can profile the database interaction to find out for certain, but I'm like 99% sure it's all columns.)  Does it make a difference?  If it does, I suspect something else is wrong in the design...

Comment: this is actually more theoretical question? What if there are 300 columns in a table and I need to update only one?

Comment: 300 columns in a single table implies to me that there's a database design issue.  300 columns might make sense for something like a data warehouse, but you generally don't interact with a data warehouse using an ORM like you would a transactional database.  The point is, the ORM is updating the object, as-is and in its entirety.  It's certainly possible to make it more granular than that, but I suspect the return on investment is well into the negative.

Comment: @David Even if it's 20 columns by 500 rows, that's a heck of a lot more data than 1 column by 500 rows.  (Especially if most columns are text and the one column is say an external ID)

Comment: @ebyrob: "Heck of a lot" is a relative term.  Updating 500 rows is also somewhat uncommon in a transactional system.  A unit of work generally updates a graph of objects, starting at one aggregate root or a small number of aggregate roots.  The relational graph is the more critical piece.  If one is doing mass-updates to tables, one is stepping outside the transaction object graph and into data manipulation/migration/etc. which is an entirely different toolset.

Comment: @David if 500 total records is "a lot" (choose another tool).  What size-range is acceptable?  100?  10?  1?

Comment: @ebyrob: I don't consider 500 records to be "a lot" in the sense of a volume of data.  But I do consider it to be uncommonly high for a single table in a unit of work in a transactional system.  The choice of another tool has nothing to do with data volume and everything to do with the nature of the task at hand.

Comment: SQL deletes and reinserts the entire ROW when it updates, so what difference does it make?

Comment: Please show me where the performance degrades if you update 1 or 500 columns.

Comment: @DanAndrews for one thing when SQL Server (for instance) "deletes or inserts" in the transaction log, it's merely writing a list of values for a point in linear history going forward to a very tightly managed file (all pre-allocated) on-disc.  When an external tool like entity-framework asks for a delete and asks for an insert, all that data goes across the network.  The whole query has to be parsed by SQL Server etc.  (It all goes through the entire pipeline instead of just being ready and going out in one spot)  PS - I don't have a copy of entity-framework I'm just amazed at the ext queries

Comment: @ebyrob I do not believe the EF sends a delete and insert statement to the database when it updates.  But SQL server internally deletes and inserts when you do an update.

Comment: @ebyrob but point taken, there will be more network traffic if all values are passed.  However, I haven't turned on my 1200 baud modem in decades - bandwidth has more capacity than my CPU and memory to compare objects before deciding which needs updated.

Comment: @DanAndrews If your network is doing over 300 megabytes (3 giga-bits) per server.  More power to you.

Comment: @ebyrob now imagine if you had to compare each of the records...  It's the lesser of two evils.  You'd still have to send the data to the server or get the current row to compare.  Please trust that I have had this debate with myself (and others) before while designing a DAL - before EF.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that granular.  (Nor should it be, as column-level tracking would introduce a whole host of complexity into concurrency tracking, which is already a difficult and compromise-ridden subject.)

When you're using an ORM (such as Linq to SQL, Entity Framework, etc.) the focus is on the object.  The framework maps that object (the entire graph of related objects, actually) into the relational database schema.  But what you're updating when you commit your changes to an ORM for persistence is the object graph.

The ORM will track which objects changed, and will make its concurrency checks at the object level in accordance with the mapping logic and concurrency rules set forth.  But it's going to compile SQL update statements for each record in its entirety as it corresponds to the object.

The state of the *object* is what changed, and so it should be persisted in its entirely new state.  While it's certainly *possible* to track changes at the column level, the return on investment for that just doesn't exist.  The code would be *vastly* more complex, which means:

- It would be far more difficult to support
- It would be far more prone to errors
- It would run much slower
- It would be far more difficult to understand and predict its behavior
- Not to mention, of course, lots of new confusion in concurrency tracking.  (Suppose User A updates the phone number for Record X, and User B simultaneously updates the address for Record X.  How would you propose those changes be merged automatically?  I'm sure you can imagine much, much more complex examples from there.)

The trade-off just doesn't add up in this case.  When using an ORM, you're updating an object.  The persistence model is abstracted (and pretty well optimized as it stands anyway).

For transactional systems, this is ideal.  When committing a unit of work for a transactional system, in the vast majority of cases you're starting with an aggregate root (or a small number of aggregate roots) and updating the graph of objects beneath them.  The relational graph is the more important piece in this scenario, and that's what the ORM is meant to handle.

For making mass-updates to targeted columns, you're no longer talking about units of work in a transactional system.  At this point you're talking about directly interacting with the table data for data manipulation, data migration perhaps, even some business intelligence tasks.  This is a whole different toolset, outside the scope of what ORMs provide.